# How to install dash to panel on Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: 17.10, gnome-shell, gnome-shell-extension

How to install dash to panel on Ubuntu 17.10 with gnome tweak tool

Comment: Question: will this override the Ubuntu Dock? That is, will installing Dash to Panel make the Ubuntu Dock disappear?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to install and activate *Dash to Panel* is from extensions.gnome.org. Open Firefox or Chrome and go to [Dash to Panel's homepage](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1160/dash-to-panel/). Click on the the toggle button at the top right to turn it ON.

[image]

**NOTE:** When you visit extensions.gnome.org for the first time it should ask you to install one browser add-on/extension. You'll have to install that extension to make this toggle button appear.

**NOTE2:** You might need to install the 'Gnome shell host connector". You do that via apt.

```
sudo apt install chrome-gnome-shell
```

It doesn't matter if you do this before or after the prompt.